# Manually read lines in python

Tags: python, file, input

I have a file that has the filename a new line, then the hashvalue of the file then a newline. This pattern repeats. Example:

```
blah.txt
23847EABF8742
file2.txt
1982834E387FA
```

I have a class called 'information' that has two member variables.

```
class information:
     filename=''
     hashvalue=''
```

Now I want to read in the file and store a filename and hashvalue in a new instance of an 'information' object and then push the instance of the information object onto a list.

The problem I am having is iterating over the file to read it. I want to read it line by line until the end of file. The problem with python's 'for line in file' method is that it grabs a line each time and I would be forced to do some kind of every other tactic to put the data in the correct member variable.

Instead, this is what I am trying to do...

```
list=[]
while(not end of file)
    x = information()
    x.filename = file.readline()
    x.hashvalue = file.readline()
    list.append(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a generator function:

```
def twolines(file):
    cur = None
    for i in file:
        if cur is None:
            cur = i
        else:
            yield (cur, i)
            cur = None
```

Then pass your file object to `twolines()`, and do something like

```
for i, j in twolines(file):
    x = information()
    x.filename, x.hashvalue = i,j
    list.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    x = information()
    x.filename = file.readline()
    if not x.filename:
       break
    x.hashvalue = file.readline()
    my_list.append(x)
```

maybe?

or

```
while True:
    x = information()
    try:
        x.filename = next(file)
        x.hashvalue = next(file)
    except StopIterationError:
        break
    my_list.append(x)
```

or my favorite

```
my_list = [filename,hashvalue for filename,hashvalue in zip(file,file)]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
list = [information(filename=x.rstrip(), hashvalue=next(it).rstrip()) for x in file]
```

Comment: file is already an iter ... you can just do `for x in file`.. and use `next(file)` instead of next(x)

Comment: `it = iter(file.readlines())` is exactly identical to `it=file`

Comment: try and run it ... set `file="A B C".split()`

Answer (score 0):

Another simple fix is by counting the lines. Introduce a variable like `line = 0` for this. now you could try the following:

```
for lines in file:
    line = line + 1
    if line  % 2 == 1:
        # This will be the filename
    else:
        # This will be the hashcode
```

Comment: Im pretty sure he explicitly stated he didnt want to do that ...  also `for i,line in enumerate(file): if i%2` would probably be a minor improvement